Weird - can't install Linux on an ITX-Machine
This is the hardest nut in Linux installation I had in 28 years.
It's an Asrock J5005-ITX-Box with a Megatrends-UEFI-Bios I bought preowned. CPU ist Pentium Silver, I use the Onboad Graphics (Intel UHD 605). Win10 is running fine so far. It has 8 gigs of RAM so it should give a decent media player.
I started with Lubuntu. I always booted from a USB stick I put an official iso on with dd from my Kubuntu Notebook.
Installation stopped directly after the "SGX disabled by BIOS" which would be a no brainer if nomodeset was not already in the boot parameter list. I added acpi=off, did not change a bit.
I tried Gentoo.
It came a bit further but stopped at Activating UDEV......unfortunately it does that even when I add noudev as boot parameter.
I tried Mint.
This looked very promising, it initialized a lot of hardware, but after it correctly detected the usb drive, it stopped.
I tried Puppy.
This went the furthest so far, it initialized everything, startet X, but could not start a window manager and the mouse did not move a bit, so I assume the box was frozen again.
I tried Rocky
It stops after "Reached target Path Units" with OK status.
I'm really clueless now. I played with secure boot and fast boot in the BIOS to no avail. I think it's some kind of hardware in the box that stopps the boot process but which?
Any hints on how to further investigate this issue is greatly appreciated. Is there any way to save the boot log except taking a picture from the screen?
@Artem
as you requested.

Awkward is the graphical boot of Fedora

Note the distorted (doubled) video. The circle turned for some seconds and then froze..

Stops means: no restart with CTRL-ALT-DELETE, only restart was power off

Clonezilla jumps into a busybox shell after a longer timeout.

Clonezilla is a different usb stick. It says "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system". In the dmesg output there are serveral traces that comes after "pcieport 000:00:13.0 can't find IRQ for PCI INT A". Tried pci=biosirq and pci=nommconf as boot parameters, did not help

Please give Fedora 40 a try. Any edition (Fedora calls them "spins") but I'm a fan of XFCE: https://fedoraproject.org/spins/xfce/download If it fails to boot, remove quiet and rhgb boot arguments from the bootloader (GRUB: press e, edit, press Ctrl + X), try to boot, make a picture and upload it here.

Please try to boot using nomodeset (add this option to kernel boot arguments). Unfortunately the i915 driver (kernel module in Linux speak) does not seem to properly support your GPU. If you're determined enough, please file a bug report here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues

There's a bug report very similar to yours: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/i915/kernel/-/issues/11171 No idea what to do, looks like your HW might be broken in Linux with no solution in sight.

nomodeset does not lead to a fedora 40 install unfortunately. I think it's the hardware has problems. Thanks for your help.

To tie up the loose end here:
I was able to install the Live System of the SliTaz-Distribution (slitaz.org). I now have network and can ssh into the box. Still working on X...
